# Can't generate Release Version from a Xamarin forms app

Tags: xamarin.forms

In Debug Mode it works, but when i'm try to use Release or generate Archive for publishing is giving me this error:

```
Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.CSharp" that could not be resolved.  
These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.

Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: 
Could not resolve reference to 'Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position' 
(defined in assembly 'AppSAV, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') 
with scope 'Plugin.Geolocator, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. 
When the scope is different from the defining assembly, it usually means that the type is forwarded. 
---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position

Time Elapsed 00:00:37.95

Package 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, 
.NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' 
instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. 
This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

I've been searching for the plugin Plugin.Geolocator, but haven't found it, only have installed the xam.Plugin.Geolocator (Don't know if it's the same).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of hours, now it's working. Needed to check the version from the plugin xam.Plugin.Geolocator from the iOS project, Android Project, PLC project, and 2 projects dependencies. They got all the same version except from one project. I Uploaded all to the same version and now can compile for Release mode.

Comment: ,Glad to hear that you have solved your issue by yourself, please remember to mark you reply as answer, it is beneficial to other community members who face the same issue, thanks.